# Dropdown list returning selected value Empty

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I use to populate Dropdown using javascript:

```
function populateDDL(ddl_id) {

var option_str = "";
var x;
for(x in datalist){

    option_str += " <asp:ListItem Value='" + datalist[x] + "' Text='" + datalist[x] + "'></asp:ListItem>"
}
var country_div = document.getElementById(ddl_id);
country_div.innerHTML = option_str;
}
```

This is sure the datalist is not empty and also Dropdown list populated perfectly..but dnt know why after clicking on my page add button I am not getting the selected value.

Thanks

Comment: asp:ListItem that you are adding in is a server side control that you are putting into the client side DOM. I'm surprised it is populating correctly to be honest but its possible that tidying up your outputted HTML (use <option> for a select list) might solve your problem.

Comment: Thanx Chris for reply but asp:ListItem too render as <option> and ddl as <select>, well I will try your suggestion too.

Comment: @chris I tried with <select> but it too return value empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should use client side select list control rather than server control to whome you are trying to fill at client side. Its surprised ...

But you should use select control

```
function populateDDL(ddl_id) {

var option_str = "<select id='ddl_id'>";
var x;
for(x in datalist){

    option_str += " <option value='" + datalist[x] + "'>" + datalist[x] + "</option>";
}
option_str += "</select>";
var country_div = document.getElementById(ddl_id);
country_div.innerHTML = option_str;
}
```

Comment: ohh.... but if its also returns empty value then their may be some problem in its filling or did you check the page source that if value filed empty their or not ...